# Doctrine: create fixtures for a certain table

Tags: doctrine, fixtures

Is it possible to create a fixtures yml file for a certain model from the data already stored in the database (e.g. like `dump-data` CLI but with specifying which data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading fixtures, you explicitly declare the models in the fixture file so this is the only way to do it, as far as I know.

If you're referring to loading fixtures into a database with existing data, loading fixtures for a specific model should not affect data in other tables, as long as you don't re-build the models. I haven't tested this though, so please do try it out in a safe environment first.

Another thing to bear in mind is that the data you upload as fixtures need to respect any foreign-key constraints you may have in your database.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't word the question correctly enough, I meant generating these yml files from data already stored it the database

Comment: @roddik: I'm not aware of this being possible. I'd approach this by writing a little custom script that pulls data from the existing database and sticks into another, or creates a CSV for use elsewhere.